# Problem reading subdirectories using FileUtils.listfiles

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to get all subdirectories doing this:

```
   File repositoryDir = new File(_props.getProperty("files.repository.path"));

IOFileFilter filter = new IOFileFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File file) {
          //return file.isDirectory();
       return true;
      }

   @Override
   public boolean accept(File arg0_, String arg1_) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
   }
  };

FileUtils.listFiles(repositoryDir,filter,null);
```

Unfortunately the List returned is empty.

On the other hand if I do this it works:

```
File[] mainLevelFiles = repositoryDir.listFiles();
```

Anyone has a clue on what wrong with Apaches FileUtils.listFiles(...)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two accept methods, one returning true and one returning false. Remove the one with the extra string, so that it looks like this:

```
IOFileFilter filter = new AbstractFileFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.isDirectory();
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you could use Apache's [DirectoryFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/DirectoryFileFilter.html):

```
 File dir = new File(_props.getProperty("files.repository.path"));
 String[] files = dir.list( DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE );
 for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
     System.out.println(files[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Actually when I try the first solution it tells me that IOFileFilter must implement the inherited abstract method IOFileFilter.accept(File,String).
I'm working with List<File> throughout my code so I need to get a List<File>.

Comment: You should extend from AbstractFileFilter. I've changed to code to reflect that.

Comment: If you have to implement IOFileFilter.accept(File,String), then why dont you just put a call back to accept(File) from it?